# Submit Video URL no longer working in Channel Videos

Tags: module, devdemon, channel-videos, syntax

My clients site has been using Channel Videos module for a couple years. Recently the 'Submit Video URL' for YouTube has stopped working, you enter a URL click OK, but nothing happens. Searching for them by Keyword still works, and both functions still work for Vimeo. I have tried to update to the latest version (3.2.0A) as noticed in the Change Log it adds support for Youtube v3 API. (Which I figured could have been the problem) But when I try and update the module as described in the documentation I get a syntax error on the site –

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /home/sites/domain.com/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/channel_videos/ft.channel_videos.php on line 293

and have had to revert back to the previously installed version. Can anyone offer any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the offending

> ? :1

from line 293 and line 342 in ft.channel_videos.php. This stopped the error and the plug-in now works. I guess it might have lost functionality connected to 'video_views' but the main purpose that it was being used is now working.